# Kendo UI Scheduler: Business hours?

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Is there any way to get Kendo UI Scheduler to display business hours in specific color?

There is just only one option in the documentation on kendo website: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/scheduler#configuration-messages.showWorkDay
which sets display message for Business hours button, but there is nothing said about how to configure scheduler to display that button. Am I missing something?

Comment: I took a quick glance through the source code, and it looks like there should be a button in the footer, where is is just a big grey empty box at the bottom of day and week views. I'm not sure why it isn't showing up, even in their demos. This is probably either a bug, or a feature that didn't get completely implemented before the last release, since it is a new widget. You might want to contact Kendo UI support and see if they know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assumed so as Scheduler widget is still under 'beta' development status. Hopefully the widget will get the requested functionality in one of the further releases as we need business hours highlight as a mandatory feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Business hours will be supported in our next official release. The documentation got updated by chance earlier.